# when i pod repo push 'xxx' 'xxx',i get error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

When I pod repo push 'ToolsModule' ToolsModule.podspec --verbose

I got this error

```
ToolsModule (0.0.1)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:32:28: error: redefinition of 'AFImageDownloadPrioritization'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:32:28: note: previous definition is here
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:40:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'AFImageDownloadReceipt'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:40:12: note: previous definition is here
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:45:53: error: property has a previous declaration
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:45:53: note: property declared here
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:50:39: error: property has a previous declaration
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:50:39: note: property declared here
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:55:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'AFImageDownloader'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:55:12: note: previous definition is here
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:60:66: error: property has a previous declaration
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:60:66: note: property declared here
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:65:53: error: property has a previous declaration
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:65:53: note: property declared here
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:70:61: error: property has a previous declaration
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:70:61: note: property declared here
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.m:84:17: error: definition of 'AFImageDownloadReceipt' must be imported from module 'AFNetworking.AFImageDownloader' before it is required
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.m:140:41: error: reference to 'AFImageDownloadPrioritizationFIFO' is ambiguous
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:33:5: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'AFImageDownloadPrioritizationFIFO'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:33:5: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'AFImageDownloadPrioritization::AFImageDownloadPrioritizationFIFO'
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.m:369:14: error: reference to 'AFImageDownloadPrioritizationFIFO' is ambiguous
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.m:372:14: error: reference to 'AFImageDownloadPrioritizationLIFO' is ambiguous
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:34:5: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'AFImageDownloadPrioritizationLIFO'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h:34:5: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'AFImageDownloadPrioritization::AFImageDownloadPrioritizationLIFO'
    - WARN  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.m:368:13: warning: enumeration values 'AFImageDownloadPrioritizationFIFO' and 'AFImageDownloadPrioritizationLIFO' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ToolsModule/ToolsModule/Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.m:47:12: error: definition of 'AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager' must be imported from module 'AFNetworking.AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager' before it is required
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.h:45:12: note: previous definition is here

[!] The `ToolsModule.podspec` specification does not validate.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:139:in `block in validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:126:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:126:in `validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:71:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

anyone know?

Comment: Go through this ref : https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Comment: I believe the question regards an issue in creating pods, not using them.